# How to get Barracuda License Token?

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

I want to setup Barracuda Web Filter on localhost, follow https://techlib.barracuda.com/BWF/VirtualDeployment

Then I config TCP/IP (I just know Barracuda for 2 hours so I don't sure this config is right): 
[image]

But in tab Licensing, I can't find token. Please help me out! 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will get that license token in email either when you purchase it or when you [download a trial](https://www.barracuda.com/download/index).